# Alt-Left on OSX to behave like Alt-Left on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, osx, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change previous/next word shortcut in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10806/how-to-change-previous-next-word-shortcut-in-bash)

When connected to a ubuntu server bash shell, I can hold **alt** key and press the **left** or **right** keys to move forward or backward a word. It is incredibly useful.

Is this behaviour defined in the .bash_profile or can it be? I.e. can I bring this behaviour into my OSX shell?

Answer (score 1):

Put this into your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
bind '"\M-\e[C":forward-word'
bind '"\M-\e[D":backward-word'
```

Checked on OS X Lion.

Comment: I can't get this to work... could I be missing something else?

Comment: Can you paste here output of this command: `fgrep ard-word $HOME/.${SHELL##*/}_profile`?